# Custom Object Initializers

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization

I've been creating custom initializers for my objects just because it feels like better practice than setting their variables in other ways. In these initializers I usually set the variables of the object then return a call to the main init.

So, for example, in a UIViewController subclass my code would look something like this:

```
-(id)initWithValue:(int)val {
    self.value = val;
    return [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
```

where `value` is an integer that belongs to that ViewController subclass, and there are usually more values than that.

However, recently I started setting self first because I thought that the `self = [self init...]` would replace the current instance of the class and thus I would lose that instance of self.
So, I have started doing:

```
-(id)initWithValue:(int)val {
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.value = val;
    return self;
}
```

I then recently checked the original version and realized that everything does work properly and the change was unneccessary.

So, my question is this:

1. What does the [super initWithNibName:bundle:] do which is causing it to create an object but not replace the original object?
2. Is one of the two versions better than the other to use or are they both equivalent? If one is better, which should be used?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code which you have written won't store the `value`, because before creation of the object you are trying to store data. 
But, the second code, needed a small modification for better practice i.e, like this...

```
-(id)initWithValue:(int)val {
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if(self)
    _value = val;

    return self;
}
```

Hope this is useful to you...:-)

Comment: That's what I thought but I tried setting the values, then doing `self = [self initWithNibName:bundle:]` then printing out the values and they were correct. I am assuming that the self will not always be altered, but it is generally safer to do it your way.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about `_value`. Just to make sure I am clear about this, when using `_value`, the `[self setValue:]` wont be called, correct? And if so is that the only reason not to use self.value or is there another?

Comment: value is property in your case, so while synthesizing use like this standard code...    
@synthesize value = _value;
     
You can able to get the value using [self setValue:] also.

Comment: This code has a major flaw, since `_value = val` is equivalent to `self->_value = val;` and the super call could return nil. The program would crash if that happens because accessing an ivar on nil is not allowed.

Comment: You need to add `if (self) { _value=val; }` so you don't try to access _value on nil

Comment: @Nick C - In this code, the first statement is the instantiating the self, and then accessing the member variables. But, anyway thanks for your suggestion..:-)

Comment: @BhanuPrakash, the problem is init can return nil. As you are assigning the result of an init to self, self can be nil after the assignment. Objc doesn't allow accessing instance variables on nil. It's like saying nil->_value = val; This is not allowed and will result in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2):

You should do it the following way:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(int)val {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _value = val;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In iOS, a common pattern is to return nil if the parameters sent to init methods are invalid. The value will be one of 2 things: the current pointer to self or nil. If the call to super returns nil then the object was not setup properly so you should also return nil. Doing self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; just makes it easier to respect the possible nil value returned by super

Comment: Note that it's actually perfectly valid to return a different object (not `nil` or the current value of `self`) from an `init` method. This is done to replace the existing object with a new one—perhaps one loaded from a nib, or one of a particular subclass, or a singleton. You should immediately store this object into `self` and use it instead of the original instance during the rest of your `init` method.

Comment: These are typically called class clusters and one should not subclass them for that reason. self would likely end up being a different subclass type of the super class so accessing the methods and instance variables define in the current class would result in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Nick, class clusters are only one of *many* reasons a superclass might return a different instance from `-init`. See Mike Ash's article [The How And Why of Cocoa Initializers](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html), and particularly the Myth/Fact section, for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code to override init method

```
 -(id)initWithValue:(int)val 
 {
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
     {
    self.value = val;
    }

   return self;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the [super initWithNibName:bundle:] actually invoke the method of the superclass.
if you use [self initWithNibName:bundle:] actually it will call the rewriting of initWithNibName:bundle: of course you must have rewrote it,otherwise it will also call the superclass method. so if you want to do some initialize in the rewrite of initWithNibName then you can use [self initWithNibName:bundle:] but if you don't need do the extra initialize there is no difference between the to method;